# What is the geometrical meaning of the theorem?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, convex-cone

### What is the geometrical meaning of the below theorem?

> Let $K$ be a closed convex cone in euclidean space $V$, and let $b\in V$, $b\notin K$. Then there exists a nonzero vector $u\in V$ such that 
>   \begin{equation*}
> \langle{x,u}\rangle\geq 0 \text{ for every } x\in K, \text{ and } \langle{b, u}\rangle<0.
> \end{equation*}

Comment: Given any closed convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and any point that’s outside the cone, there’s a hyperplane with the cone completely on one side, and the point on the other side.

Comment: Yeah..you are right..I could visualize it from $\langle x,u \rangle \geq 0 $ for every $x\in K$ but what does that $\langle b,u \rangle < 0$ mean?

Comment: And if you dont mind, kindly give me some reference to study these concepts. the book which I refer by Berman seems to be little difficult to visualize.

Comment: A good reference would be Boyd’s book “Convex Optimization”

Comment: Also, the vector $u$ defines a separating hyperplane. $\langle b,u\rangle<0$ means that $b$ lies strictly on one side of the hyperplane defined by $u$. Drawing a picture in 2D helps

Comment: @DavidM. Thank you so much..If possible, kind consolidate your comments and post it as an answer. I will accept it. If possible, with the picture in 2D graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem says that given a closed convex cone $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $b$ that's not in the cone, there exists a hyperplane (defined by its normal vector $u$) so that the cone is completely on one side of the hyperplane, and the point $b$ is on the other side. Here's a picture:

[image: Illustration of cone]

Note that the inner product $\langle{u,x}\rangle\geqslant0$ since the angle between $u$ and $x$ is less than $\pi$ radians. In contrast, $\langle{u,b}\rangle<0$, since the angle is greater than $\pi$ radians.

The books I have used for convex geometry (with applications to optimization) are Boyd's book Convex Optimization, and Nemhauser and Wolsey's book Integer and Combinatorial Optimization.

Comment: oh..Thank you soooo much for the detailed answer. I am currently preparing a course work material out of it. May I use your pic in my material to explain the theorem? Look like you have used `tikz` to plot it. May I get the code?(or else I will reproduce with your permission). my email: daviddgl2013@gmail.com

Comment: and thank you so much for the references.

Comment: I created the figure with an online tool called draw.io. Feel free to use my figure or draw your own.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have redrawn the pick using `tikz` and used it.